# how to convert GCCRandom(Mersenne Twister by Takuji Nishimura and Makoto Matsumoto) from Game Coding Complete by Mike McShaffry 4E to stl random

Tags: c++, random, stl, game-engine, mersenne-twister

I am trying to translate the book Game Coding Complete by Mike McShaffry 4E to modern C++17 standard and faced with the code of Mersenne Twister by Takuji Nishimura and Makoto Matsumoto.
Is it right to convert random generator code from book like that:
from:

```
#include <ctime>
#define CMATH_N 624
#define CMATH_M 397
#define CMATH_MATRIX_A 0x9908b0df   /* constant vector a */
#define CMATH_UPPER_MASK 0x80000000 /* most significant w-r bits */
#define CMATH_LOWER_MASK 0x7fffffff /* least significant r bits */
#define CMATH_TEMPERING_MASK_B 0x9d2c5680
#define CMATH_TEMPERING_MASK_C 0xefc60000
#define CMATH_TEMPERING_SHIFT_U(y)  (y >> 11)
#define CMATH_TEMPERING_SHIFT_S(y)  (y << 7)
#define CMATH_TEMPERING_SHIFT_T(y)  (y << 15)
#define CMATH_TEMPERING_SHIFT_L(y)  (y >> 18)
typedef int INT;
typedef unsigned int UINT;
#define MAXUINT ((UINT)~((UINT)0))
#define MAXINT ((INT)(MAXUINT >> 1))
class GCCRandom {
private:
    unsigned int rseed;
    unsigned int rseed_sp;
    unsigned long mt[CMATH_N]; /* the array for the state vector  */
    int mti; /* mti==N+1 means mt[N] is not initialized */
public:
    GCCRandom() {
        rseed = 1;
        rseed_sp = 0;
        mti = CMATH_N + 1;
    }
    unsigned int Random(unsigned int n) {
        unsigned long y;
        static unsigned long mag01[2] = { 0x0, CMATH_MATRIX_A };
        if (n == 0)
            return(0);
        if (mti >= CMATH_N) { /* generate N words at one time */
            int kk;
            if (mti == CMATH_N + 1)   /* if sgenrand() has not been called, */
                SetRandomSeed(4357); /* a default initial seed is used   */
            for (kk = 0; kk < CMATH_N - CMATH_M; kk++) {
                y = (mt[kk] & CMATH_UPPER_MASK) | (mt[kk + 1] & CMATH_LOWER_MASK);
                mt[kk] = mt[kk + CMATH_M] ^ (y >> 1) ^ mag01[y & 0x1];
            }
            for (; kk < CMATH_N - 1; kk++) {
                y = (mt[kk] & CMATH_UPPER_MASK) | (mt[kk + 1] & CMATH_LOWER_MASK);
                mt[kk] = mt[kk + (CMATH_M - CMATH_N)] ^ (y >> 1) ^ mag01[y & 0x1];
            }
            y = (mt[CMATH_N - 1] & CMATH_UPPER_MASK) | (mt[0] & CMATH_LOWER_MASK);
            mt[CMATH_N - 1] = mt[CMATH_M - 1] ^ (y >> 1) ^ mag01[y & 0x1];
            mti = 0;
        }
        y = mt[mti++];
        y ^= CMATH_TEMPERING_SHIFT_U(y);
        y ^= CMATH_TEMPERING_SHIFT_S(y) & CMATH_TEMPERING_MASK_B;
        y ^= CMATH_TEMPERING_SHIFT_T(y) & CMATH_TEMPERING_MASK_C;
        y ^= CMATH_TEMPERING_SHIFT_L(y);
        return (y % n);
    }
    float Random() {
        float r = (float)Random(MAXINT);
        float divisor = (float)MAXINT;
        return (r / divisor);
    }
    void SetRandomSeed(unsigned int n) {
        /* setting initial seeds to mt[N] using         */
        /* the generator Line 25 of Table 1 in          */
        /* [KNUTH 1981, The Art of Computer Programming */
        /*    Vol. 2 (2nd Ed.), pp102]                  */
        mt[0] = n & 0xffffffff;
        for (mti = 1; mti < CMATH_N; mti++)
            mt[mti] = (69069 * mt[mti - 1]) & 0xffffffff;
        rseed = n;
    }
    unsigned int GetRandomSeed() {
        return rseed;
    }
    void Randomize() {
        SetRandomSeed((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    }
};
```

to code with std::mt19937 engine and std::uniform_int_distribution:

```
#include <random>
#include <limits>
#include <chrono>
class MTRandom {
private:
    unsigned int m_rseed = 1;
    unsigned int m_rseed_sp = 0;
    static const unsigned int MAXINT = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    std::mt19937 m_engine;
public:
    MTRandom() { m_engine.seed(m_rseed); }
    unsigned int Random(unsigned int n) {
        std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int> distr(0, n);
        return distr(m_engine);
    };
    float Random() {
        std::uniform_real_distribution<float> distr(0.0f, 1.0f);
        return distr(m_engine);        
    }
    void SetRandomSeed(unsigned int n) {
        m_engine.seed(n);
        m_rseed = n;
    }
    unsigned int GetRandomSeed() {
        return m_rseed;
    }
    void Randomize() {
        SetRandomSeed((unsigned int)std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now()));
    }
};
```

Comment: why not use `std::uniform_real_distribution` in the implementation of `Random()`?

Comment: are you talking about the float Random() class method? for example, write like this: float MTRandom::Random() {
 std::uniform_real_distribution<float> distr(0.0f, 1.0f);
 return distr(m_engine);
}

Comment: yup, the method.  note that this question might be better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm confused that the end of the interval in std::uniform_real_distribution is not included in set. like [a, b)

Comment: it will do the same as your original code as far as I can tell.  in your old code the modulus will exclude the max value, so after division you'll never get 1

Comment: it just occurred to me that my last statement is (probably) incorrect.  strictly speaking it'll depend on the size of an `int` on your platform.  e.g. with a 32bit int, a 1.0f would have been returned for values `> MAXINT - 64`, so you'll get a 1.0 returned for 63 of the 64 possible values.  the bottom of https://prng.di.unimi.it/ talks a bit about generating uniform floating point values.  i'd also suggest using sized integer types (e.g. `uint32_t`) to reduce this platform/compiler dependence/ambiguity

Comment: from what you say is it follows that the original algorithm from the book does not work correctly on a 64-bit machine?

Comment: it depends on how your compiler interprets `int` and `long`.  I tend to use Linux where an `int` matches the register size (so 64bits on a 64bit machine) but AFAIK Microsoft compilers have been forced to fix ints at 32bits otherwise they'd break compatibility too much.  hence your code might work under windows with a MS compiler, but break elsewhere.  C allows you to write portable code, it's just not convenient!